# Flyway - Springboot - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, flyway

Do, still, I need to run the Flywydb image as Kubernetes Job to run database migrations from Springboot deployed in Kubernetes (EKS & Openshift)?

I see some references of Flyway being configured that way. However, in case of Springboot, Flyway migrations are run as part of start cycle.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options: You can either use flyway as part of your application or you can use a separate container, for example as an initContainer in Kubernetes.
If you feel more comfortable with having flyway as part of your application and run in similarly to your local development environment, just go ahead.

Comment: Yes, the later approach is what is followed - Flyway is run as part of the Springboot application.

Comment: This is a valid option and does not have any kubernetes dependency as well, so it is portable to many different environments.